# Remove first element from the linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm working on my own linked list class. Everything works fine.
The remove fonction works also, but if I try to remove the first element, then the application stops responding.

I have no idea, what do I wrong.

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class linkedList {

private:
    struct elem {
        elem* p;  // pointer
        T v;      // value

        elem* next() {
            return p;
        }
    };

    int elems = 0;
    elem* first;

    elem* last() {
        if(first == 0) return 0;

        elem* e = first;
        while(e->p != 0) {
            e = e->p;
        }

        return e;
    }

    elem* getP(int index) {
        int i=0;
        elem* e;

        e->p = first;
        while(i!=index) {
            e = e->p;
            i++;
        }

        return e->p;
    }

public:

    T& get(int index) {
        int i=0;
        elem* e;

        if(elems<index) throw 0x77;

        e->p = first;

        while(i!=index) {
            e = e->p;
            i++;
        }

        return (e->p)->v;
    }

    void add(T el) {
        elem* u = last();
        elem* e = new elem;

        e->p = 0;
        e->v = el;

        if(u == 0) {
            first = e;
        } else {
            u->p = e;
        }

        elems++;
    }

    int size() {
        return elems;
    }

    void remove(int index) {
        if(elems<index) throw 0x77;

        if(index == 0) {
            elem* e = first->p;
            first->p = e->p;
            delete e;
            elems--;
        } else {
            elem* p = getP(index-1);
            elem* e = p->p;
            elem* n = e->p;

            delete e;
            p->p = n;

            elems--;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    linkedList<int> myList;

    myList.add(10);
    myList.add(12);
    myList.add(4);
    myList.add(7);

    myList.remove(0);

    cout << myList.get(0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use single character variable names, because they are very effective in obfuscating your code, making it hard to comprehend and easy to overlook errors.

Comment: Please, create a constructor that initialize your members to something... You're chekcing `first` against `nullptr` but never guarantee something is assigned to it beforehand ! The default constructor does not set the element to `nullptr`...

Comment: If Johan's tipp with initalizing the members does not work for you I suggest you google for "debugger + <YOUR IDE>" and try to follow your program flow manually. It will help you to spot errors in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `remove(int)` method, when `index`is 0 you set the pointer of the first element instead of setting the pointer to the first element:

```
void remove(int index) {
    if(elems<index) throw 0x77;

    if(index == 0) {
        elem* e = first;
        first = first->p; // Set first instead of first->p
        delete e;
        elems--;
    } else {
        elem* p = getP(index-1);
        elem* e = p->p;
        elem* n = e->p;

        delete e;
        p->p = n;

        elems--;
    }
}
```

By the way: it might be, that you have some more mistakes related to this in your code, that don't cause errors.